# Using jQuery in ios 8 app extension javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios8, ios8-extension

I'm following the [The App Extension Guide: Accessing a Webpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1) to extract some content from a page.

Is it possible to use jQuery inside my javascript file and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to inject jQuery into the page but was not able to successfully determine the time when I could run jQuery code after that. DOMNodeInserted executes but probably in a different context than page DOM.

```
MyExtensionJavaScriptClass.prototype = {
run: function(arguments) {

            var my_awesome_script = document.createElement("script");
            my_awesome_script.setAttribute("src","//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js");
            if (my_awesome_script.addEventListener) {
               my_awesome_script.addEventListener ('DOMNodeInserted', OnNodeInserted, false);
            }

            document.head.appendChild(my_awesome_script);


     function OnNodeInserted (event) {
            // event comes out undefined and $ is also undefined
            $(document).on('paste', function(e){ alert('You just pasted!') });
     }
```